# Detect permalinks when passing querystring in REST API requests

Tags: plugins, rest-api, query-string

Let's say I'm using `wp_localize_script` to pass base REST url to my script in a Wordpress plugin:

```php
wp_register_script( 'my-plugin', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '../dist/admin-main.js', [], '0.9.2' );
wp_localize_script( 'my-plugin', 'MY_PLUGIN_WP_REST_API_CONFIG', [
      'baseUrl' => esc_url_raw( rest_url() ),
    ] );
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-plugin' );
```

In my JS files I need to fetch some data using query strings in my GET request, like so:

```js
const baseUrl = MY_PLUGIN_WP_REST_API_CONFIG.baseUrl;

fetch(baseUrl + 'wp/v2/custom_post_type?per_page=100&order=asc').then(response => ...);
```

However, the above will only work with 'cool' permalinks, when the url resolves to something like `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/custom_post_type?per_page=100&order=asc`.

When not using pretty permalinks, this would translate to `https://example.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/custom_post_type?per_page=100&order=asc`, which is invalid, because there would be multiple `?` signs in the querystring, thus throwing 404 error on the request.

Is there a best practice that I'm missing where I would detect the permalink structure and construct my querystring based on some data passed from backend? The obvious solution in my case would be to parse the `baseUrl` variable in javascript and add some sort of a conditional, but that seems too hacky and error prone to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In more recent browsers (everything but IE, essentially), there are some useful APIs for working with URLs that will make this easier:

```
let url = new URL( MY_PLUGIN_WP_REST_API_CONFIG.baseUrl );

url.searchParams.append( 'per_page', 100 );
url.searchParams.append( 'order', 'asc' );

fetch( url.toString() ).then();
```

With those methods the `per_page` and `order` parameters will be added correctly regardless of whether or not the original URL has a query string. But as I mentioned, these aren't available in IE, although there is a polyfill available [here](https://github.com/ungap/url-search-params). You're using `const` and `fetch()` though, so I'm not sure this is a concern for you.

A more blunt solution that would work in any browser could be to just check if the URL contains a `?`, and if it does, use a `&` character to add your parameters, otherwise use a `?`:

```
var baseUrl = MY_PLUGIN_WP_REST_API_CONFIG.baseUrl;
var params  = 'per_page=100&order=asc'

if ( baseUrl.indexOf( '?' ) > -1 ) {
    var url = baseUrl + '&' + params;
} else {
    var url = baseUrl + '?' + params;
}

fetch( url ).then();
```

Libraries like axios or jQuery might also have ways to handle adding parameters to a URL that are more sophisticated than `fetch`, which doesn't have functionality for adding query parameters other than including them in the URL string.

Comment: Thanks, Jacob. I had no idea about the searchParams API, I will use that. I was hoping there is something I can do on backend, perhaps to set a default sort order and 'posts per page' value, but I presume that would mean creating a whole custom endpoint.